# using non-standard evaluation with formula Bis

Tags: r, tidyeval, quosure

Non-Standard evaluation in R.  I want to send a formula to a function that uses `lm`.

I have a data frame with one response: y and many predictors.  I will fit a model inside a function.  The function will receive a filtering criteria as a string and the name of the predictor variable as a string.  The response will enter as a name.  The function will filter on the filter criteria, then fit the a model using the predictor variable that was sent to it as a string.  I can't get the predictor string to work correctly.

This is very close to [using non-standard evaluation with formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837200/using-non-standard-evaluation-with-formula).
In fact I illustrate that solution, which gets me part of the way there.
Difference: I want to send a string with the value of my predictor instead of sending the predictor to the function.

Use Case: Eventually I will put this in a shiny ap and let the user select the predictor and response as well as the filter.

Here is what works:

```
# create a data frame.
n <- 100
levels_1 <- sample(c("a","b","c"),n,replace=TRUE)
levels_2 <- sample(c("a","b","c"),n,replace=TRUE)
d <-tibble(l_1 = levels_1 ,l_2 = levels_2, y = rnorm(n))

# A function that works
my_lm <- function(d,predictor,response,filter_criteria){
  d1 <- d %>% filter(l_2 == 'a')
  lm(y ~ l_1,data=d1)
}
my_lm(d,l_1,y,'a')

my_lm2 <- function(d,predictor,response,filter_criteria){
  enquo_predictor <- enquo(predictor)
  enquo_response <- enquo(response)
  enquo_filter_criteria <- enquo(filter_criteria)
  d1 <- d %>% filter(l_2 == !!filter_criteria)
  form <- as.formula(paste(enquo_response, " ~ ", predictor)[2])
  # form <- as.formula(paste(enquo_response, " ~ ", enquo_predictor)[2])  wrong way to do it.
  lm(form,data=d1)
  #lm(!!enqu_preditor ~ !!enquo_response,data=d1)
}

selected_var <- names(d)[1]
selected_var
filter_value <- 'a'
my_lm2(d,l_1,y,filter_value)  # This works but is not what I want.
my_lm2(d,selected_var,y,filter_value)  # This does not work but is what I want to work.
```

Comment: Your question might be easier to read if you wrote in words at the bottom what exactly the problem is. Right now it's hidden in comments in the code, and it took me a while to see them. Also, why is there a line commented out in `my_lm2`?

Comment: You want the same function to work with both unquoted symbols and variables need to be evaluated to point to strings? That's very confusing. How is the function supposed to know the difference?

Comment: I just figured it out.